# Any guidelines for making android apps for Samsung TV

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

Are there any tutorials or guidelines available on the web for making android apps for the Samsung TV exclusively?

Here's the link:

http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungapps/?cid=ppc_hdt_goo_Apps_TV%20Apps_tv+apps

Looking forward for feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

The Samsung TV isn't an android platform.  It's basically a web browser with some plug-ins.  If you've got a Javascript app that run in the android browser, it's likely you could port it to the TV.  I don't think this belongs in an android forum.

I signed up and got their tools, but I didn't see any sample projects, and the documentation is very clumsy.

Comment: +1 on the very clumsy docs. And +1 on it not being Android, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried samsung developer forum?
http://www.samsungdforum.com